# GCP Pub/Sub subscriber not receiving messages in Apache Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Background : I am using a GCP dataflow (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) in streaming mode to process information. Dataflow receives data from GAE Endpoint through Pub/Sub. I am using apache beam wrapper function for subscribing -
beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(...). Dataflow is running always, and pub/sub subscription is waiting for new data.

Issue :  I am noticing that, after some days (no fixed pattern on how many days), it stops receiving any message. Publishing part in GAE works fine, as I can see message Id returned to me.

Troubleshoot : when I restart dataflow (by cloning), it works again.

Suspect : Since I am relying on beam's api, I am not sure what's happening underneath. Is this a bug with beam.io.ReadFromPubSub or bug with dataflow.

Note : Tried https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting, but no relevant help.

Comment: Can you describe your pipeline? Do you have logs trace when the pipeline stops? Do you use windowing in the pipeline? Does the pipeline work as expected until its end?

Comment: In addition to the information requested by @Guillaume, please provide the following: 1- your pipeline code (please hide any sensitive information such as keys or personal information). 2- the beam SDK version that you are using. 3- In the subscription input, how do you see the graphs 'Unacked message count' and 'Oldest unacked message age' during the period where you observed that the messages stopped being processed? If possible, please attach a screenshot.